# why column null return nothing in linq

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

in mysql this query return rows:

```
SELECT * FROM conta.subrecurso as a 
left join conta.recurso as b on a.idRecurso=b.idRecurso
left join conta.eventorecurso as c on b.idRecurso=c.idRecurso
left join conta.recursocliente as d on a.idSubrecurso=d.idSubrecurso 
left join conta.eventocliente as e on d.idVenta=e.idVenta
WHERE c.idEvento=47 and e.idVenta is null ;
```

but this translate to linq does not return anything:

```
var subrec4 = (from sr in db.subrecurso
                       join r in db.recurso on sr.idRecurso equals r.idRecurso
                       join er in db.eventorecurso on r.idRecurso equals er.idRecurso
                       join rc in db.recursocliente on sr.idSubrecurso equals rc.idSubrecurso
                       join ec in db.eventocliente on rc.idVenta equals ec.idVenta
                       where er.idEvento == idEvento && ec.idVenta==null
                       select sr).toList()
```

I dont know how get the rows where the relation with other column table is null.
The model of the query is here:

```
    public int idVenta { get; set; }
    public int idEvento { get; set; }
    public int idCliente { get; set; }
    public string tipoCliente { get; set; }
    public int nroReserva { get; set; }
    public decimal montoTotalBs { get; set; }
    public bool fact { get; set; }
    public int cantidadPersonas { get; set; }
    public decimal aCuentaBs { get; set; }
    public decimal saldoBs { get; set; }
    public decimal descuentoBs { get; set; }
```

Comment: Your linq query is semantically `INNER JOIN`, not `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: yes left Join was the solution